# Linking error of R package with Rcpp: "undefined symbol: LAPACKE_dgels"

Tags: c++, r, linker-errors, rcpp, lapack

I am creating an R package 'lapacker' to provide the C interface for internal LAPACK library provided and used by R (with double precision and double complex only) using the R API header file "R_ext/Lapack.h". The source code:
https://github.com/ypan1988/lapacker/

And the project structure:

```
/lapacker
  /inst
    /include
      /lapacke.h
      /someother header files
  /R
    /zzz.R
  /src
    /lapacke_dgetrf.c
    /lapacke_dgetrf_work.c
    /loads of other utility functions provided by LAPACKE 
    /rcpp_hello.cpp
  DESCRIPTION
  NAMESPACE
```

Inside the project, I tried a test function in rcpp_hello.cpp file (Note this example is coming from https://www.netlib.org/lapack/lapacke.html#_calling_code_dgels_code):

```
//'@export
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void example_lapacke_dgels()
{
  double a[5][3] = {{1,1,1},{2,3,4},{3,5,2},{4,2,5},{5,4,3}};
  double b[5][2] = {{-10,-3},{12,14},{14,12},{16,16},{18,16}};
  lapack_int info,m,n,lda,ldb,nrhs;
  int i,j;

  m = 5;
  n = 3;
  nrhs = 2;
  lda = 3;
  ldb = 2;

  info = LAPACKE_dgels(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR,'N',m,n,nrhs,*a,lda,*b,ldb);

  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    for(j=0;j<nrhs;j++)
    {
      printf("%lf ",b[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

The whole package can compile properly with no errors, and in R it gives the right answer(indicating symbol LAPACKE_dgels can be found):

```
> example_lapacke_dgels()
2.000000 1.000000 
1.000000 1.000000 
1.000000 2.000000
```

However, when I create a separate C++ file, say demo3.cpp with exactly the same function,

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

#include <lapacke.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(lapacker)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void lapacke_dgels_test()
{
  double a[5][3] = {{1,1,1},{2,3,4},{3,5,2},{4,2,5},{5,4,3}};
  double b[5][2] = {{-10,-3},{12,14},{14,12},{16,16},{18,16}};
  lapack_int info,m,n,lda,ldb,nrhs;
  int i,j;

  m = 5;
  n = 3;
  nrhs = 2;
  lda = 3;
  ldb = 2;

  info = LAPACKE_dgels(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR,'N',m,n,nrhs,*a,lda,*b,ldb);

  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    for(j=0;j<nrhs;j++)
    {
      printf("%lf ",b[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

it no longer compiles properly (actually I tried under both macOS and ubuntu, same linking problem), and gives linking error messages (Cannot find symbol LAPACKE_dgels):

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp("~/Desktop/demo3.cpp", showOutput = TRUE)
/usr/lib/R/bin/R CMD SHLIB -o 'sourceCpp_6.so'  'demo3.cpp'  
g++  -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I"/home/yipan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include" -I"/home/yipan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/lapacker/include" -I"/home/yipan/Desktop"    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c demo3.cpp -o demo3.o
g++ -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o sourceCpp_6.so demo3.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
Error in dyn.load("/tmp/RtmpUsASwK/sourceCpp-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-1.0.0/sourcecpp_159e6145591d/sourceCpp_6.so") : 
  unable to load shared object '/tmp/RtmpUsASwK/sourceCpp-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-1.0.0/sourcecpp_159e6145591d/sourceCpp_6.so':
  /tmp/RtmpUsASwK/sourceCpp-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-1.0.0/sourcecpp_159e6145591d/sourceCpp_6.so: undefined symbol: LAPACKE_dgels
```

I have also checked the lapacker.so under /R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/lapacker/libs and found:

```
000000000000c6b0 g    DF .text  00000000000001bf  Base        LAPACKE_dgels
```

Do I miss something to get the demo3.cpp compile correctly? Thanks very much for your patience and time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are facing a difficult problem here. The Symbol you are trying to resolve `LAPACKE_dgels` is part of `lapacker.so`, build during package installation. Problem is, that the libraries for R packages are not meant for linking. Instead, they are loaded by R dynamically at run-time. Basically, I see four possibilities:

1. Convert `lapacke` into a header only library and install that in `inst/include` (c.f. `RcppArmadillo`).
2. Link with a system installation of `lapacke` (easy on Linux ...)
3. Register all functions with R and use the methods provided by R to link to them (c.f. [WRE](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Linking-to-native-routines-in-other-packages) and `nloptr`).
4. Compile a library meant for linking and install it with the R package. You will still need a plugin for that to work, since you have to add `-L<path/to/lib> -l<libname> ....` to `PKG_LIBS`.

I am sure there are examples on CRAN that use method 4, but none comes to mind right now. However, as a "code kata" I have converted a recent test package of mine to use this structure, c.f. https://github.com/rstub/levmaR/tree/static.

---

(Original incomplete answer.)

In `src/Makevars` you have

```
PKG_LIBS = $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)
```

You need an analogue setting when compiling a cpp file via Rcpp attributes. The best way achieve this is by using an Rcpp plugin, c.f. [RcppArmadillo's solution](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/master/R/inline.R) (adjustments are untested!):

```
inlineCxxPlugin <- function(...) {
    plugin <-
        Rcpp::Rcpp.plugin.maker(
                  include.before = "#include <lapacke.h>",
                  libs           = "$(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)",
                  package        = "lapacker"
              )
    settings <- plugin()
    settings$env$PKG_CPPFLAGS <- "-I../inst/include"
    settings
}
```

BTW, why do you want to interface with LAPACK directly, when RcppArmadillo does so already?

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. But I get the feeling that it may generate the same error as I did exactly the same thing for another pkg 'cblasr' (both internal and separate C++ file compile correctly). I am aware of armadillo and actually I use Rcpp and RcppArmadillo in several projects. I am implementing a matrix library to practice C++, and unfortunately it is row major ordering. If I want to use BLAS and LAPACK internally, best choice is to use cblas.h and lapacke.h which are not provided by R. Put 'LinkingTo: cblasr, lapacker' in 'DESCRIPTION' of matrix R pkg and I will get same link error.

Comment: @ypan1988 You are right, my initial solution would have be incomplete. See the update. BTW, I am surprised that it did work for `cblasr`.

Comment: Thanks again! I managed to fix the problem and the best way to go is through option 1 -- changing the library into a head only one. I was getting a bit confused with "LinkingTo" at the beginning, and it mainly add the additional directory for the header files.